# Node - connect-flash not working on redirect

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I'm running into some weird issues with connect-flash, I've used it in other projects in the exact same manner and it worked fine, here is what I have:

**Some Route**

```
if (err) {
    req.flash('message', [{
      class: 'alert-danger',
      message: 'TEST'
    }]);

    res.redirect('/error');
}
```

**error route**

```
router.get('/error', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('---in error route')
  console.log(req.flash('message'));

 res.render('error', {
    message: req.flash('message'),
    layout: layout
  });
})
```

**console.log**

```
---in error route
[ { class: 'alert-danger', message: 'TEST' } ]
```

**error.hbs**

```
{{#if message}} 
    {{#each message}}
        <div class="{{this.class}}">{{this.message}}</div>
    {{/each}} 
{{/if}}
```

Clearly it's in there, but there is no printout, if I copy the exact smae thing from the first route to error, it displays (which won't work for me, but just for testing to make sure the hbs template logic works):

```
router.get('/error', function (req, res, next) {

  req.flash('message', [{
    class: 'alert-danger',
    message: 'TEST'
  }]);
  res.render('error', {
    message: req.flash('message'),
    layout: layout
  });
})
```

It's probably something simple, but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok after some experimentation and by pure accident, I found out that **The console.log apparently clears the flash!!!!**

I hope this helps anyone who runs into this issue.

Comment: If you use an IDE debugger and put a watch on `req.flash()`, that will clear it too

Answer (score 4):

I know you already found a solution, but for anybody with the same issue, what the problem actually is is that when you use `req.flash()` to retrieve the flash messages, it actually **deletes** that message after retrieving it.

Had you done this:

```
console.log(req.flash('message'));
console.log(req.flash('message'));
```

You would have received something similar to this output:

```
[ 'TEST' ] 
[]
```

This is because the first call to `req.flash('message')` retrieves **and**
deletes the given message.

Additionally, had you done this:

```
req.flash('message');
console.log(req.flash('message'));
console.log(req.flash('message'));
```

You would have received output that was similar to this:

```
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of express you are using. I was having the same issue as I was using express 4.x.x with connect-flash. Connect-flash works with express 3.x.x and Connect-flash-plus works with express 4.x.x.